# Why is an object not stongly typed in a foreach with var?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tabpage, member-access

i was writing the following

```
if(this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count != ImagesList.Count())
{
    foreach (var item in this.tabControl1.TabPages)
    {

    }
}
```

and i couldn't access the controls inside each item using item.
But with a defining it's type like

```
if(this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count != ImagesList.Count())
{
    foreach (TabPage item in this.tabControl1.TabPages)
    {

    }
}
```

i could easily access them using `item.Controls`

so i was wondering **why do i really need to define/cast those items as `TabPage`**, shouldn't the compiler/intellasense figure it out as each item inside `this.tabControl1.TabPages` is actually a `TabPage` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`TabControl.TabPages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) returns a [`TabPageCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.aspx) which does not implement the strongly typed  `IEnumerable<T>` but the non-generic  `IEnumerable` interface  which returns an object.

So if you provide the type in the `foreach` it will be casted implicitely. If you don't provide the type it's type is `object` and you need to cast it later.

Read [*C# language spec, 8.8.4*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more informations.

You could also use the Linq extension method `Enumerable.Cast`:

```
foreach (var item in this.tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>())
{
    // item is TabPage
}
```

It's handy especially if you want use Linq:

```
var tabs =  this.tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
     .Where(tp => tp.Name.StartsWith("MyTabPage"));
```

Comment: i wasn't expecting to get such helpful answer :) thank you also for the linq snippet , accepting in 8 mins

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to to this?

```
foreach (TabPage t in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    foreach (Control c in t.Controls)
    {
        string a = c.Name;
    }
}
```