# Why foreach var in EventLogEntryCollection not returning EventLogEntry?

Tags: c#, collections, system.diagnostics

I've researched about IEnumerable and IEnumerator there's a lot of way on how to make a class useable for foreach statement. But that doesn't answer my question. Why is the EventLogEntryCollection used in foreach loop does not return EventLogEntry? But if I changed var to EventLogEntry it works the way I expected using for loop.

```
       EventLog eventLog1 = new EventLog
        {
            Log = myLogName,
            Source = "sourcy"
        };

        EventLogEntryCollection collection = eventLog1.Entries;
        eventLog1.Close();

        foreach (var v in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Message); //object does not contain definition for Message

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Message of the EventLog is :"
               + collection[i].Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the `EventLogEntryCollection` used in foreach loop not return `EventLogEntry`?

Because it's old code, pre-generics. It [merely implements `ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrycollection?view=netframework-4.7.2), which inherits the non-generic [`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_IEnumerable_GetEnumerator) used by your `foreach()` loop.

So the item type of that enumerator is `object`, and that doesn't contain a `Message` property.

> But if I changed var to `EventLogEntry` it works the way I expected using for loop.

That's exactly what you need to do to fix this.

See also [Object type not recognised on foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156252/object-type-not-recognised-on-foreach-loop).

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer. Doc link for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrycollection?view=netframework-4.7.2